# Configure Glassfish http-listener to Port 443/ 80

Tags: webserver

I want to configure the http-listeners in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 Build 5 under Linux. I changed the settings for the http-listener-1 to the port 80 and the settings for the http-listener-2 to the port 443. The aim is that they listen to these ports and not to the default ports 8080 and 8181. So the domain.xml looks like this:

```
<network-listeners>
          <network-listener port="80" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="443" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
</network-listeners>
```

I tried it via console, admin-console and editing manually the file. As a result I can't start Glassfish and get this error under Ubuntu 12 and Red Hat 6.4:

```
java.net.BindException: permission denied: 443=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@239190ce
    at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.initSelector(TCPSelectorHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.grizzly.TCPSelectorHandler.preSelect(TCPSelectorHandler.java:378)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.doSelect(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:188)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectorHandlerRunner.run(SelectorHandlerRunner.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:21.761+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 18ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:21.762+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 33ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:21.957+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|The Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded.|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:22.105+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (5) Startzeit: Felix (3.772ms), Startservices(1.766ms), gesamt(5.538ms)|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:22.106+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|v3 wird aufgrund einer Startausnahme heruntergefahren: Keine Berechtigung: 80=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@6254067e|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:22.199+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Herunterfahren des Servers initiiert|#]

[#|2013-08-21T12:02:22.209+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=38;_ThreadName=Thread-21;|Already stopped, so just returning|#]


Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)"

Command start-domain was not successful.
```

So I have the same error like this guy:
https://www.java.net//node/693510

Is there a way to reach the aim without using iptables or port redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to run this server as a normal user, and not as root.

In order to [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) a TCP listener to a port under 1024 on most operating systems, you have to have root or equivalent privilege. This is a security feature, to prevent normal user programs from squatting on well-known service ports. (These are called [privileged ports](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPApplicationAssignmentsandServerPortNumberRang-2.htm).)

This is why the first line of your error report contains "permission denied."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As a security measure I created a seperate user "glassfish" for the application server without root rights or equivalent privileges. So what would you recommend? At the moment I think a port redirection with iptables would be the best solution.

Comment: @user2047688: That's one way. You can also put it behind a normal web server configured as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). This has benefits such as off-loading delivery of static content, so that the Glassfish instance only has to deliver dynamic content.